# Is there a better way to solve this than using multiple for loops?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that will score the Keirsey Bates personality test. The user passes a string that's 70 characters long and the string is evaluated based on the scoring method [here](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/103/Projects/Keirsey/ManualScoring.html).

I've rewritten the program with help from the answers given below, but now it's not counting the "A"s and "B"s right for the third and last letters of the personality type. I can't figure out why; since they're all in the same for loop, shouldn't the counts be right for everything?

Also, if there is anything that you see that can be simplified or made cleaner, I'm open to suggestions!

Here is the program I've written:

```
public class KeirseyScorer {
   public static String evaluateSurvey(String responses) {
      int surveyLength = 70, columnNumber;
      String first = "", second = "", third = "", last = "", result = "";
      int numAFirst = 0, numBFirst = 0, numASecond = 0, numBSecond = 0, numAThird = 0, numBThird = 0, numALast = 0, numBLast = 0;

      if(responses.length() != surveyLength || !responses.matches("[AB]*")) {
         result = "ERR!";
      }
      else {
         for(int i = 0; i < surveyLength; i++) {
            columnNumber = i % 7;
            if(columnNumber == 0) {
               if(responses.charAt(i) == 'A') {
                  numAFirst++;
               }
               else {
                  numBFirst++;
               }
            }
            else if(columnNumber == 1 || columnNumber == 2) {
               if(responses.charAt(i) == 'A') {
                   numASecond++;
               }
               else {
                   numBSecond++;
               }
            }
            else if(columnNumber == 3 || columnNumber == 4) {
               if(responses.charAt(i) == 'A') {
                   numAThird++;
               }
               else {
                   numBThird++;
               }
            }
            else {
                if(responses.charAt(i) == 'A') {
                    numALast++;
                }
                else {
                    numBLast++;
                }
            }
         }
         first = checkValues(numAFirst, numBFirst, "E", "I", "X");
         second = checkValues(numASecond, numBSecond, "S", "N", "X");
         third = checkValues(numAThird, numBThird, "T", "F", "X");
         last = checkValues(numALast, numBLast, "J", "P", "X");
         result = first + second + third + last;
      }
      return result;
   }
   public static String checkValues(int a, int b, String aGreater, String bGreater, String tie) {
      String answer = "";
      if(a > b) {
          answer = aGreater;
      }
      else if(a < b) {
          answer = bGreater;
      }
      else {
          answer = tie;
      }
      return answer;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one `String` so you can do this with only one loop.

Instead of using a separate loop for each personality dimension, you can simply take the current index in the string and use the remainder operator to find the column number, like this:

```
int columnNumber = characterIndex % 7;
```

This will be zero for the first column, six for the final column, and so on. If the columnNumber is zero then you're dealing with an answer which applies to the E/I personality dimension; one or two will mean the S/N dimension; three or four will mean the T/F dimension; five and six will mean the J/P dimension.

Rather than use multiple variable to keep count, I would use a single `Map<String, Integer>` to hold the counts for each letter, so if you find an "A" in the first column then you can increment the count of "E" like so:

```
Integer count = mapFromTypeToScore.get("E");
if (count == null) {
    count = 0;
}
mapFromTypeToScore.put("E", ++count);
```

Then at the end you just need to pull from the map the score for "E" and "I" and declare the type for that dimension to be the one with the highest count, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Let me give it a try. :)

Comment: So when I'm incrementing the count for "I", do I have to repeat the 2nd block of code you put up?

Comment: Yes, the second block goes in the loop. You would determine the column number based on the current position within the answers string, then the personality dimension based on the column and the value of the current answer ("A" or "B"), and then you would use the second block of code to get the previous score from the Map and then add one to it before putting it back in the Map.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. So if I understand correctly, we would have to do this for every dimension. Wouldn't this make the method very long then? (I need to get the method under 50 LOC to fit my instructor's standards) :(

Answer (score 1):

All those condition checks and for loops can be placed into a method of their own, in which you pass the specific values for each case as parameters. For example, the if/else as a single method:

```
public void checkVals(int a, int b, String c, String d, String e){
    if ( a > b ) return c;
    if ( a == b ) return d;
    return e;
}
```

Then just call the method and assign the appropriate variable to the returned value

Comment: So if I wanted to put the for loop into its own separate method, what would be the best way to do that? (I was also thinking about using the answer below to change how I determine the column value)